# How do I stop KDE wallet password request when connected remotely through VNC

Tags: kubuntu, kde, password, vnc, kwallet

I am using Kubuntu 20.04 (but had same issue in Kubuntu 18.04). I am running TigerVNC server on it and whenever I connect to the VNC server, I sometimes get a KDE Wallet popup requesting a password .

[image]

It always shows up when I open Google Chrome. This doesn't happen when I am using the PC physically.

Based on my understanding, the KDE Wallet is the password manager for KDE plasma and it has the same master password as your login by default. When you login physically, the KDE wallet gets unlocked. This doesn't happen with VNC and whenever you open an application that needs to use the wallet, it will request for password. Is there a way to unlock the KDE Wallet at the creation of the VNC server or whenever a user connects to the server?